# Замена спецсимволов в javascript

Tags: javascript

В приложении с сервера приходят строки содержащие в себе спецсимволы формата "&#1105 ;". Существует ли в javascript средство позволяющее расшифровывать спецсимволы подобного рода, например
&#1105 ; -> ё?

В данный момент решаю проблему поиском в строке символов &# и ; и заменяя полученную строку на соотвествующий символ.

Comment: `innerHTML` сам это сделает

Comment: Спасибо, помогло